# Can't install Imagemagick on Mac with Brew

Tags: imagemagick

I am using Brew v0.8 on my Mac OS Lion.

When I am trying to install Imagemagick:

```
MacBook-kir:rails kir$ brew install imagemagick
/usr/bin/git
==> Cloning https://github.com/adamv/ImageMagick.git
Cloning into /Users/kir/Library/Caches/Homebrew/imagemagick--git...
fatal: https://github.com/adamv/ImageMagick.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
Error: Failure while executing: git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/adamv/ImageMagick.git /Users/kir/Library/Caches/Homebrew/imagemagick--git
```

How to install Imagemagick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your brew installation and reset the repository:

```
cd /usr/local
brew update
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Then you can run:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the mirror that brew downloads ImageMagick from was moved.

Try running `brew update` and then `brew install imagemagick` again