# Failure to install ImageMagick with Brew

Tags: macos, shell, imagemagick, osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't install Imagemagick on Mac with Brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434008/cant-install-imagemagick-on-mac-with-brew)

I'm trying to install ImageMagick on OS X Lion but get the following error:

```
[~]$  brew install imagemagick
/usr/bin/git
==> Cloning https://github.com/adamv/ImageMagick.git
Cloning into /Users/isilber/Library/Caches/Homebrew/imagemagick--git...
fatal: https://github.com/adamv/ImageMagick.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
Error: Failure while executing: git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/adamv/ImageMagick.git /Users/isilber/Library/Caches/Homebrew/imagemagick--git
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

update your brew formulas:

```
brew update
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your brew installation and reset the repository:

```
cd /usr/local
brew update
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Then you can run:

```
brew install imagemagick
```