# Install imagemagick & graphicsmagick fail

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I can't install imagemagick & graphicsmagick. Error: Failed to download resource "libpng".

```
tranduchieu:~ $ brew install graphicsmagick
==> Installing dependencies for graphicsmagick: libpng, freetype
==> Installing graphicsmagick dependency: libpng
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.simplesystems.org/pub/libpng/png/src/libpng16/libpng-1.6.18.tar.xz

curl: (78) RETR response: 550
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://dl.bintray.com/homebrew/mirror/libpng-1.6.18.tar.xz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "libpng"
Download failed: https://dl.bintray.com/homebrew/mirror/libpng-1.6.18.tar.xz
```

Comment: me too getting the same error. Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460047/cant-install-imagemagick-with-brew-on-mac-os-x-mavericks

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

`$ brew update`
and after
`$ brew install graphicsmagick`

It solved problem for me.